# How to get the second value using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have two date values in my text file and I want to find the second date using regex my text is given below

From: dummy one . To: dummy two Page:1/2 **Date: 12/10/2014**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla at bibendum odio. Aliquam turpis nisl, fermentum a consequat eget, placerat id ante. Etiam non lacus nisl. Nullam id tincidunt elit

name :dummy 3   **Date: 12/11/2014**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla at bibendum odio. Aliquam turpis nisl, fermentum a consequat eget, placerat id ante. Etiam non lacus nisl. Nullam id tincidunt elit

I want get the second date **12/11/2014** my current  regex expression is given below

```
(DATE:)\s*(?<PLAYDATE>\d{1,2}[/|-]\d{1,2}[-|/](?:\d{4}|\d{2})).*\r\n
```

its returns first date I'm a rookie in regex so please help me 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn on case insensitive modifier `i` in-order to do a case-insensitive match.

```
(?is)(DATE:)\s*(?<PLAYDATE>\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[-/](?:\d{4}|\d{2}))(?!.*\bDate:)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/5)

`(?!.*\bDate:)` Asserts that the string following the date won't contain another `Date:` substring.

Comment: If I want to restrict this for only a specific text containing string dummy one ,How can I implement that

Comment: one more doubt how to prevent this expression execute for other texts

Comment: just add the string you want to ignore inside the negative lookahead `(?!...)`

Answer (score 1):

Just take the second match. Supposing `file` is where the text is, you can do

```
Regex.Matches(file, @"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}/")[1].Value
```